# Scale Color Viridis - greyscale

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm trying to make my plot grayscale; tried using scale_color_greyscale instead of viridis but I'm getting an error that says "a continuous value supplied to discrete scale". my 'distance' variable is continuous though

```
  geom_sf(data = df, aes(color = distance),
          lwd = 0.1, alpha = 0.3)+
 scale_color_viridis(breaks = c(20, 40, 60))
```

Comment: What package provides the function `scale_color_greyscale` ? It isn't a standard `ggplot2` scale. I'm also confused by `scale_color_viridis` because the latest `ggplot2` doesn't have that either - and if it did, a "breaks" argument would be strange. I think you need to provide more details about which packages and R version you are using, and a more complete code example.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: If it's just for printing, the viridis color scales print grey scale well. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your data and expected result, but there are `scale_fill_grey` and `scale_fill_gradient2` for greyscale.

> scale_fill_grey (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_grey.html)

```r
scale_colour_grey(
  ...,
  start = 0.2,
  end = 0.8,
  na.value = "red",
  aesthetics = "colour"
)
```

> scale_fill_gradient (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html)
> Referenced StackOverflow post: [heatplot ggplot2 error different behaviour between scale_fill_gradient2 and scale_fill_grey Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40182481/5567893)

```r
scale_colour_gradient(
  ...,
  low = "white",
  high = "black",
  space = "Lab",
  na.value = "grey50",
  guide = "colourbar",
  aesthetics = "colour"
)
```

Instead of using scale_color_viridis, try them.

Answer (score 0):

scale_color_grey() only works for discrete variables, which is why you're getting an error when using it for a continuous variable that is compatible with viridis.